# Magnifying drawing in picturebox

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing

I'm working on a project that we should draw Line,Circle, ... on a picturebox,
The program should be capable to zoom in/zoom out,
But when i want to zoom on picturebox.Image because drawing is not part of image it does not work,
Please Help me

Comment: Graphics.ScaleTransform() provides zooming.  PictureBox does not.  Use the Paint event.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to zoom in the image and the drawings you should draw them on the image directly. so just create a graphics object for the image

```
  Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(picturebox.Image);
```

then draw all of you graphics using the g variable.